# In-method inner class vs class level inner class

Tags: java, concurrency, jit

I was writing something like this :

```
class Root {
    public void action() {
        List<Foo> param1;
        List<Foo> param2;

        class Node implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                // read param1, some stuff, insert in param2
            }
        }

        tpe ThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(..);

        // And submit some work, a few times
        tpe.submit(new Node());
        tpe.submit(new Node());

        // some stuff with param1 & 2
    }
}
```

And then I was wondering is there is no performance issue with this. If the fact that I declare the inner class within a method, and use a local variable would not impact performance, maybe the JIT compilator would never be able to optimize the execution of the inner class because of the context around it.
So I wrote something like this, which do exactly the same thing :

```
class Root {
    class Node implements Runnable {

        List<Foo> param1;
        List<Foo> param2;

        public Node(List<Foo> param1, List<Foo> param2) {
            this.param1 = param1;
            this.param2 = param2;
        }

        public void run() {
            // read param1, some stuff, insert in param2
        }
    }

    public void action() {
        List<Foo> param1;
        List<Foo> param2;

        tpe ThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(..);

        // And submit some work, a few times
        tpe.submit(new Node(param1, param2));
        tpe.submit(new Node(param1, param2));
    }
}
```

The app is under heavy load, so I was wondering the best way to do it from a performance point. Can anyone provide an insight ?

Comment: I don't see why there should be a difference.

Comment: Should `param1` and `param2` be fields of `Node` in your second example? They are not declared. The first example is also not obvious. `param1/2` could only be accessed when the are a field of `Root` of when they are captured through a closure from inside `action()`. This would however require an anonymous Node class and them being final.

Comment: Yes they are fields of Node. I've fixed that in my post. In the first exemple indeed params are final and the context is captured in to save the variable for the thread. This is what makes me question performance of it. Why would I need to make an anonymous node class ?

Comment: You  might want it to have (read-only) access to a method-local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The class declaration happens at compile-time, not at run-time. There is no run-time performance difference.